# Highlight partial duplicates in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates

I use a Google sheet to track cheques that have been sent, what invoices they pay and when they are cashed in. Since one cheque often pays more than one invoice I write this information in this format:  ####-####-####-####

is there a way to highlight partial doubles in a specific column? The problematic invoices are always from the same supplier and with a 4digit reference. I don't mind switching the format if it can make it easier.

[image: Google sheet example]

Thanks in advance.

Tried a few formulas I found on internet that I did not understand and which did not seem to work.
I did not find anything in the suggestions that would answer my question either

[image: im expecting something like this]

Comment: could you please elaborate more on the partial doubles? that part makes it hard to decipher exactly what you need. There are formulas to highlight duplicates in a column. if it is just a segment of the full number you want to apply the logic, then you can maybe extract that segment into another column and apply the conditional formatting in that column

Comment: In Collum D, I enter the invoice numbers paid by a single cheque as 4 digits separated by a -.     Ex: 4112-4113-4114.       I would like to highlight cells if there is a repetition of an invoice number,. As in exemple screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
=NOT(ARRAYFORMULA(COUNT(SEARCH(SPLIT(D2,"-"),D:D)))=COUNT(SPLIT(D2,"-")))
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this does exactly what I want. ♥